# Laravel error when including models

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

In `config\auth.php` i've changed from `'driver' => 'database'` to `'driver' => 'eloquent'`And now when the user wants to log in an error appears:

```
ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 412: 
 include(C:\xampp\htdocs\bluedrive\drive/app/User.php): failed to open stream: 
 No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening and how could I fix it?

Comment: Did you tried `composer dumpautoload` within your terminal

Comment: @Uchiha Wouldn't that dump all autoloads?

Comment: @Uchiha Well then...how will all stuff autoload?

Comment: Did you tried `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: @Uchiha I haven't. I'm affraid that the whole app will break

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your `Authentication Model` (in `config\auth.php` ) is wrongly defined.

It must define a valid `eloquent` model :

```
'model' => App\User::class
```